# Can't get facebook android sdk login to work with native app installed

Tags: android, facebook, mobile

I'm developing an android app that uses facebook authentication to login and publish videos to user's timeline. I followed the facebook tutorial, other blogs tutuorials but I can't get the integration work at all when the native facebook app is installed. I've already checked out the hash and got the hash with the following code, but always get the same CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED status.

```
try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.myApp", 
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());

            Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
```

With that in hand,I configured the hash in my facebook app and everything works fine when the native facebook app is installed. But when I install it the error starts to happen every time.

Here's the code of the login part

```
Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception)                {
            if (session.isOpened()) {
                //doing some stuff in here

            }
        }
    });
```

And here I override the onActivityResult

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: did you follow all of the steps described in the docs?https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.0

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer ... Yeap... Followed all the same steps and still CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Got it to work... for some misterious reason, even the hash generated with the code above, it wasn't the correct hash. I added a Toast notification showing the hash and it worked.